# Query a geopackage with a simple features polygon using {sf}

Tags: r, gdal, r-sf, geos

I have a large geopackage. I want to read in features from it, that intersect with another geopackage. I am trying this but I'm obviously doing something wrong:

```
box <- st_read("file1.gpkg", quiet=T) %>% st_bbox()

layer_name <- st_layers("file2.gpkg")$name

my_query <- glue("SELECT * FROM {layer_name} WHERE st_intersects(geom, st_polygon('{box$xmin} {box$ymin}, {box$xmax} {box$ymin}, {box$xmax} {box$ymax}, {box$xmin} {box$ymax}, {box$xmin} {box$ymin}'))")

st_read("file2.gpkg", query = my_query)
```

If I print the query it looks like this, is it formatted correctly?

```
SELECT * FROM li_final_town_areas WHERE st_intersects(geom, st_polygon('9.25 47, 9.5 47, 9.5 47.25, 9.25 47.25, 9.25 47'))
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : 
  Query execution failed, cannot open layer.
```

Comment: I get "No such function: st_polygon" on anything that tries to use "st_polygon". Maybe its only using OGRSQL and not SQLITE SQL. Although `st_buffer` works.... Hmmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form of the query, using `st_polygonfromtext` with the polygon as WKT, works for me:

```
q2 = "SELECT * FROM gadm36_BTN_2 WHERE st_intersects(geom, st_polygonfromtext('POLYGON(( 90  27,  91 27, 91 28, 90 28 , 90 27 ))' ))"    
BTN2 = st_read(gpkg, query=q2)
```

Here's the selected level-2 regions of Bhutan inside level-0 Bhutan with the selection polygon lats and longs added. Seems to work!

[image]

Comment: Ah, I've not tried polygonfromtext ... I'll try.

Comment: Great stuff. Yep. Just testing in my full code now and it seems to do what I want (which is split up a complex geopackage of many polygons into polygon 'tiles' using a pre-defined grid).

Comment: Seems that this approach is *really* slow unfortunately @spacedman . Back to the drawing board for me. Argh.

Comment: The most performant I found was this:

ogr2ogr -clipsrclayer grid_cell.gpkg -f GPKG output.gpkg input_polygons.gpkg -makevalid

Comment: But if there are no features in the output, the extent of the geopackage is set to the bounds of the world (-180,-90,180,90). But I want it to have the bounds of the 'crop'.

Comment: I'll try and make a reprex.